# Extract time stamps from string and convert to R POSIXct object

Tags: r, lubridate

Currently, my dataset has a time variable (factor) in the following format:

```
weekday month day hour min seconds +0000 year
```

I don't know what the "+0000" field is but all observations have this. For example:

```
"Tues Feb 02 11:05:21 +0000 2018" 
"Mon Jun 12 06:21:50 +0000 2017"
"Wed Aug 01 11:24:08 +0000 2018"
```

I want to convert these values to `POSIXlt` or `POSIXct` objects(year-month-day hour:min:sec) and make them numeric. Currently, using `as.numeric(as.character(time-variable))` outputs incorrect values.

Thank you for the great responses! I really appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem you can get by without using `lubridate`. First, to extract individual dates we can use `regmatches` and `gregexpr`:

```
date_char <- 'Tue Feb 02 11:05:21 +0000 2018 Mon Jun 12 06:21:50 +0000 2017'
ptrn <- '([[:alpha:]]{3} [[:alpha:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2} \\+[[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{4})'
date_vec <- unlist( regmatches(date_char, gregexpr(ptrn, date_char)))

> date_vec
[1] "Tue Feb 02 11:05:21 +0000 2018" "Mon Jun 12 06:21:50 +0000 2017"
```

You can learn more about regular expressions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html).

In the above example `+0000` field is the UTC offset in hours e.g. it would be `-0500` for `EST` timezone. To convert to R date-time object:

```
> as.POSIXct(date_vec, format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y', tz = 'UTC')
[1] "2018-02-02 11:05:21 UTC" "2017-06-12 06:21:50 UTC"
```

which is the desired output. The formats can be found [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html) or you can use `lubridate::guess_formats()`. If you don't specify the `tz`, you'll get the output in your system's time zone (e.g. for me that would be `EST`). Since the offset is specified in the format, R correctly carries out the conversion.

To get numeric values, the following works:

```
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct(date_vec, format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y', tz = 'UTC'))
[1] 1517569521 1497248510
```

**Note:** this is based on uniform string structure. In the OP there was `Tues` instead of `Tue` which wouldn't work. The above example is based on the three-letter abbreviation which is the standard reporting format.

If however, your data is a mix of different formats, you'd have to extract individual time strings (customized regexes, of course), then use `lubridate::guess_formats()` to get the formats and then use those to carry out the conversion.

Hope this is helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to reproduce the transition from factor to char, but starting from that this code should work:

```
t <- unlist(strsplit(as.character("Tues Feb 02 11:05:21 +0000 2018")," "))
strptime(paste(t[6],t[2],t[3], t[4]),format='%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')
```

PS: More on date formats and conversion: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html